# UNEXCEPTED TOP LEVEL EXCEPTION when building OsmAnd

Tags: android

When I try to build OsmAnd in Android Studio (this Version: https://f-droid.org/repo/net.osmand.plus_145_src.tar.gz) it Fails with 23 Errors. The first is UNEXPECTED TOP LEVEL EXCEPTION and they are all from Android DEX. Not one is from the normal code.

Here is a screenshot:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7PIyoRznmeueEVGRXQ5QW8xb3M/edit?usp=sharing

It contains all Errors.

Thank you in advance for helping me

Comment: I also am having this problem, did you ever find a solution?